# How to use Javascript transfer replace function to replace multiply characters?

Tags: php, javascript, replace

I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function transfer(which) {
        which = which.replace(/[\-]+/g,'-');    // to remove extra hypens
                which = which.replace( 'č', 'c' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ē', 'e' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ģ', 'g' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ī', 'i' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ķ', 'k' );
                which = which.replace( 'ļ', 'l' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ņ', 'n' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ū', 'u' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ž', 'z' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'š', 's' ); 
                which = which.replace( 'ā', 'a' );  
        which = which.replace(/\s/g,'-'); // to replace spaces with hypens
        which = which.replace(/[\-]+/g,'-');    // to remove extra hypens
        which = which.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'').toLowerCase(); // to convert to lower case 
        document.getElementById("url_slug").value = which;
   }
</script>
```

As you see, right now there are many changed characters, but I need also change all russian characters to latin. If I do it that way, I will be very long code.
So my question is: is it possible with Javascript transfer replace function replace many characters not one character per line.
Something similar like in PHP

```
 $cyr  = array('а','б','в','г','д','e','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у', 
        'ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ь', 'ю','я','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У',
        'Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ь', 'Ю','Я' );
        $lat = array( 'a','b','v','g','d','e','zh','z','i','y','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u',
        'f' ,'h' ,'ts' ,'ch','sh' ,'sht' ,'a' ,'y' ,'yu' ,'ya','A','B','V','G','D','E','Zh',
        'Z','I','Y','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U',
        'F' ,'H' ,'Ts' ,'Ch','Sh' ,'Sht' ,'A' ,'Y' ,'Yu' ,'Ya' );
        $textcyr = str_replace($cyr, $lat, $textcyr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function in JavaScript to do this, but you can create your own quite easily. Create a Russian-to-Latin mapping in an object, and then loop over that object using `for..in`. For each key-value pair handled by the loop, do a replace.

```
function transfer(which) {
    // define a Russian-to-Latin mapping object
    var map = {
                'б':'b',
                'в':'v',
                 // all the rest ...
              };

    // replace non-Latin chars with Latin replacements
    for(cyr in map) {
        var lat = map[cyr];
        which = which.replace(new RegExp(cyr, 'g'), lat);

        // Or without RexExp: 
        //   which = which.split(cyr).join(lat);
    }

    // general cleanup
    which = which.replace(/\s/g,'-')      // spaces to hyphens
                 .replace(/[\-]+/g,'-')   // remove duplicate hyphens
                 .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'').toLowerCase();

    // show the result
    document.getElementById("url_slug").value = which;
}
```

Note that when `replace` is used with a string as its first argument, it only replaces the first instance of the string (e.g., `"aaa".replace('a','b')` returns `"baa"`, not `"bbb"`). You need to use a global regular expression to replace a string multiple times, as I do in my example. Just make sure your Russian doesn't have any special regex characters like `^`, `$`, `(`, `)`, etc. (but from your example, I'm guessing this won't be a problem). **Alternatively**, you can use the `split`/`join` solution that I've added as a comment.

Depending on your needs, you could provide the `map` object as an argument, instead of having it built into the function.

Comment: Thanks. It works great, but only how to implement in this code this:    which = which.replace(/\s/g,'-'); // to replace spaces with hypens
        which = which.replace(/[\-]+/g,'-');    // to remove extra hypens
        which = which.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'').toLowerCase(); // to convert to lower case

Comment: I edited in some code for that -- you can chain your `replace` calls together, as I do in the "general cleanup" section. That way, you don't have to write out "`which = which.replace(...);`" many times; you just add more `.replace(...)` calls. There' is no way to make it any shorter than that, because the "spaces to hyphen" replacement must happen before the "remove duplicate hyphens" replacement.

Comment: Thanks. But this time code didnt worked. With first code all worked except space remover. Maybe is it possible somehow to change?

Comment: My original code ended `return which`, but I later changed it to match the final `getElementById` line that you use in your original code. Could that be the problem? (By the way, I've added a safer solution that doesn't require passing a string into a RegExp constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

Friend, there is no build-in method in javascript like `str_replace`... but you can create this method by creating a function in this name... attach this below function in your javascript file or under a `script` tag in your html page...

```
function str_replace(search, replace, subject){ // same as php
    for(var i=0;i<search.length;i++){
        subject=subject.replace(new RegExp(search[i],"g"),replace[i]);
    }
    return subject;
}
```

How to use:

```
var cyr = ['а','б','в','г','д','e','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м',
           'н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ',
           'ъ','ь','ю','я','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ж','З','И',
           'Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х',
           'Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ь', 'Ю','Я'],
    lat = ['a','b','v','g','d','e','zh','z','i','y','k','l','m',
           'n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f','h','ts','ch','sh',
           'sht','a','y','yu','ya','A','B','V','G','D','E','Zh',
           'Z','I','Y','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U',
           'F' ,'H' ,'Ts','Ch','Sh','Sht','A','Y','Yu','Ya'];

textcyr = str_replace(cyr, lat, textcyr);
```

if you want to change the method name `str_replace` to something else just change the function name...